# IPFS uri format: https://ipfs.io/ipfs/<CID> vs. ipfs://<CID>?

Tags: uri, ipfs, opensea, tokenuri, imageuri

Here is my test tokenURI.json file w/ the imageURI I pass to my token contract.setTokenURI():

```
{
 "attributes": [
    {
      "trait_type": "location",
      "value": "West Awesomeville"
    },
    {
      "display_type": "date",
      "trait_type": "created",
      "value": 1535250800
    }
  ],
  "description": "My awesome NFT.",
  "image": "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmaUXii41ESnUMxLJUoVcrEeXowz7RHcdTiumvrBmUvcwG?filename=test4.png",
  "name": "NFT 1"
}
```

Which is the best IPFS uri form to use esp. if I want to load this NFT into Opensea?

The docs in IPFS recommend:

```
https://ipfs.io/ipfs/<CID>
```

but the docs in Opensea recommend:

```
ipfs://<CID>
```

Which form is better and why?

In the above json I'm using the first form recommended by IPFS. It works but loading into Opensea is slow/somewhat unpredictable.

The form Opensea recommends is shorter, no gateway. Would the image load faster in Opensea if I used the 2nd form?

[IPFS docs: Address IPFS on the Web](http://docs.ipfs.io.ipns.localhost:8080/how-to/address-ipfs-on-web/#dweb-addressing-in-brief)

[Opensea docs:](https://docs.opensea.io/docs/metadata-standards) 
*If you use IPFS to host your metadata, your URL should be in the format ipfs://CID. For example, ipfs://QmTy8w65yBXgyfG2ZBg5TrfB2hPjrDQH3RCQFJGkARStJb.*

Answer (score 5):

The ipfs:// url is the better way. Because gateways can go down. Now the ipfs pinner that you're using (pinata.cloud?) can also go down, or you can stop paying them and they will disappear your stuff.

Opensea is not likely to care, as long as they can find your metadata / images from the uri returned by the contract they will list your thing, and there's a  way somewhere to do a metadata refresh (if you do a reveal)

And if I can also suggest, it probably might be a good idea to include a way to update the baseURI in the contract just in case.